# How to generate a more accurate distribution of sample of random variates?

Tags: r, conditional-probability, simulation, resampling, quantiles

I want to generate a sample of random variates choosing 5 out of 7 days of the week, $X_1,\ldots,X_5$, such that the aggregate counts resemble a given day-of-week profile, namely
$$\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{I}_i(X_1)+\cdots+\mathbb{I}_i(X_5)]=5p_i$$ 
for $i=1,\ldots,7$.

I am using the traditional inverse transform method with pseudo-random uniform U numbers and the desired cumulative distribution. Why is the sample distribution flatter than the generating distribution?

I am assuming it has to do somehow with conditional probabilities. Assuming the pseudo-random numbers are acceptable, what is the best way to accomplish this?

Below stands my implementation in R:

```
counts <- c(2268, 3232, 4173, 4113, 4079, 3877, 2648)
dow.pdf <- counts / sum(counts)
dow.cdf <- cumsum(dow.pdf)

randDow <- function(n) {
  dow <- NULL
  while (length(dow) < n) {
    #generate pseudo-random number
    U <- runif(1, min = 0, max = 1)

    #find the position in the CDF
    rv <- which.min(U > dow.cdf)

    #check for duplicates
    if (!(rv %in% dow)) {
      dow <- c(dow, rv)
    }
  }
  return(sort(dow))
}

#generate 10000 random variates method 1
s1 <- t(replicate(10000,c(sort(sample(1:7,5,rep=F,prob=dow.pdf)))))

#generate 10000 random variates method 2
s2 <- t(replicate(10000, randDow(5)))

#summarize sample results
ps1 <- table(s1)/sum(table(s1))
ps2 <- table(s2)/sum(table(s2))

#compare visually
barplot(matrix(c(dow.pdf, ps1, ps2), nr=3, byrow=TRUE), beside=T, 
    names.arg=1:7, main="Day of Week Distribution")
legend("topleft", c("pdf","ps1", "ps2"), pch=15, cex=0.7,
   bty="n")
```

Comment: Can you clarify what "I want to generate a sample of random variates choosing 5 out of 7 days of week such that the aggregate counts resemble a given day-of-week profile" means?

Comment: Means when counting the number of times each day of week appears in the sample, the proportions with respect to the total match the desired proportions.

Answer (score 4):

**Update [02/30]:** As my colleague Robin Ryder pointed out to me, the problem is solved in Brewer's book [Sampling with unequal probabilities](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387908072). This resolution is actually [discussed](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/111497/7224) in an earlier [Cross validated question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/110178/7224). It is however unclear to me whether or not there exists a sampling strategy with fixed probabilities, in the sense of running

`sample(1:N,n,rep=FALSE,prob=q)`

to produce the sample with expected frequencies $p_i$...

---

The traditional inverse cdf method works for a *single* simulation. However, if you generate 5 draws *without replication*, according to the frequencies given by `counts`, the marginal distribution of those draws is no longer the empirical cdf `dow.cdf`. The fact that both your methods lead to highly similar frequencies is reflecting upon this difference.

For instance, consider the formal case when `counts=c(1000,100,1,1))` and you draw `n=2` out of 4 without replacement: because of the huge imbalance between the first two counts and the last two counts, most draws by `sample((1:4),2,rep=FALSE,prob=c(1e3,1e2,1,1))`  will be `1 2` despite 2 having a probability ten times smaller. As shown by the picture below:[image]

However, if the number of draws is reasonably small against the number of possible values and if the probabilities are not too different, there may exist a solution. For instance, if one generates only 2 draws out of 7 possible values, and if one wants to achieve the probability vector $\mathbf{q}$ on the resulting sample, the sampling probability vector $\mathbf{p}$ is solution of the equations $(i=1,\ldots,7)$
$$
2q_i=p_i+\sum_{j\ne i} p_j\,\frac{p_i}{1-p_j}
$$
While solving this equation in a closed form is not feasible, a recursion based on the fact that the uniform probability is a fixed point may produce a solution. Here is an example where it works:

```
#function to be inverted
targ=function(p){
  p*(2-length(p)+sum(1/(1-p))-1/(1-p))}
#component in the above
nores=function(p,i=1){
  2-length(p)+sum(1/(1-p[-i]))}
#target probability
kuh=(1:7)/sum((1:7))
#probability when resampling 
peh=rep(1,7)/7
while (sum(abs(2*kuh-targ(peh)))>.001){
  i=sample(1:7,1)
  peh[i]=2*kuh[i]/nores(peh,i)
  peh=peh/sum(peh)
  }
```

Running this code leads to

```
> peh
[1] 0.03261515 0.06597545 0.10094319 0.13761820 0.17673115 0.21921258 0.26690427
```

and checking that it works:

```
> s1 <- t(replicate(10000,c(sort(sample(1:7,2,rep=F,prob=peh)))))
> table(s1)/sum(table(s1))
s1
      1       2       3       4       5       6       7 
0.03710 0.07225 0.10695 0.13990 0.17630 0.21545 0.25205 
> kuh
[1] 0.03571429 0.07142857 0.10714286 0.14285714 0.17857143 0.21428571 0.25000000
```

But if one picks a more extreme repartition of the draws, like

```
kuh=(1:7)^5/sum((1:7)^5)
```

there is no solution (found by this recursive approach).
Extending to more draws is equally feasible if a wee bit more cumbersome. For instance, here is the version for 3 draws:

```
targ=function(p){
  q=rat=p/(1-p)
  for (i in 1:7){
    dble=outer(rat[-i],p[-i],'*')
    tple=dble/(1-outer(p[-i],p[-i],'+'))
    q[i]=1+sum(rat[-i])+sum(tple)-sum(diag(tple))}
  return(p*q)}
nores=function(p,i=1){
  rat=p/(1-p)
  dble=outer(rat[-i],p[-i],'*')
  tple=dble/(1-outer(p[-i],p[-i],'+'))
  1+sum(rat[-i])+sum(tple)-sum(diag(tple))}
```

which leads to a solution using the iterative pluggin approach as follows:

```
kuh=(1:7)/sum((1:7))
peh=rep(1,7)/7
while (max(abs(3*kuh-targ(peh)))>.001){
  i=sample(1:7,1)
  peh[i]=3*kuh[i]/nores(peh,i)
  peh=peh/sum(peh)}
```

as it stops at

```
> peh
[1] 0.02797048 0.05788001 0.09031821 0.12651015 0.16894929 0.22434742 0.30402444
```

which is close enough to the target:

```
> max(abs(3*kuh-targ(peh)))
[1] 0.0004822188
```

Comment: Thanks Xi'an. I understand your point. The sample() function in R already adjusts the probabilities when the sampling is without replacement (according to the documentation). My custom function is trying to do the same numerically. I am not concerned about the difference of the two sampling methods. What I am concerned is about the difference between the desired counts distribution and the resulting counts distribution.

Comment: Yes, the resulting imbalance is the problem. How to overcome that imbalance is the exact question still unanswered. I have modified the counts by trial-an-error to achieve approximate balance. However, I believe there must be some theoretical way to calculate.